# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm getting this error while  testing the contract.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

```
const{expect} = require("chai");
const hre = require("hardhat");


 describe("Token Contract", function(){

it("Deployment should assign the totalSupply of tokens to the owner", async function()
{
    const signers = await ethers.getSigner();
    const owner = signers[0];

    console.log("Signers Object:", owner);

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");

    const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

    const ownerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);

    expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.be.equal(ownerBalance);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.

```js
// this is wrong
const signers = await ethers.getSigner();
// this is correct
const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
```

`getSigner` is still a valid command, but it doesn't return an array. That's why `signers[0]` returned `undefined`.

Comment: still getting the same error in the terminal

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Token.js:20:65)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

Comment: This code works for me

```
const {expect} = require("chai");

const {hre} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

    const signers = await ethers.getSigners();

    const owner = signers[0];

    console.log("address:", owner.address);

}

main()
```
hardhat version "^2.6.5"

Answer (score 3):

add this line to hardhatconfig.js:
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

and add this to your testfile :
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
.......
i was facing the same error even after following the hardhat official docs, but adding above code worked for me

Comment: Now this is @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Simply add --- **require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")** ---- on hardhat.config.js